# How Can i compare two lists of different objects and return match?

Tags: python, list, object

I want to take this two lists and compare them,

```
list1 = [(Joe Black, married, happy),(Mili Cis, unmarried , happy),(Gary Oldman, married, unhappy)]
list2 = [Joe Black,Gary Oldman]
```

I would like to have new list :

```
list3 = [(Joe Black, married, happy),(Gary Oldman, married, unhappy)]
```

Where references to objects are from list1.

Comment: What is those types? is the list contains strings?

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to post this code:

```
list1 = [('Joe Black', 'married', 'happy'), ('Mili Cis', 'unmarried', 'happy'), ('Gary Oldman', 'married', 'unhappy')]
list2 = ['Joe Black', 'Gary Oldman']
```

Then this list comprehension is what you want:

```
list3 = [(name,status,desc) for (name,status,desc) in list1 if name in list2]

print(list3)
```

Output:

```
[('Joe Black', 'married', 'happy'), ('Gary Oldman', 'married', 'unhappy')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Normal Method:

```
list1 = [("Joe Black", "married", "happy"),("Mili Cis", "unmarried" , "happy"),("Gary Oldman", "married", "unhappy")]
list2 = ["Joe Black","Gary Oldman"]
a = []
for i in list1:
    if i[0] in list2:
        a.append(i)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[('Joe Black', 'married', 'happy'), ('Gary Oldman', 'married', 'unhappy')]
```

Using List Comprehension:

```
list1 = [("Joe Black", "married", "happy"),("Mili Cis", "unmarried" , "happy"),("Gary Oldman", "married", "unhappy")]
list2 = ["Joe Black","Gary Oldman"]
a = [i for i in list1 if i[0] in list2]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[('Joe Black', 'married', 'happy'), ('Gary Oldman', 'married', 'unhappy')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `list3 = [x for x in list1 if x[0] in list2]`

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the names are strings for this answer.

```
list1 = [(Joe Black, married, happy),(Mili Cis, unmarried , happy),(Gary Oldman, married, unhappy)]
list2 = [Joe Black,Gary Oldman]
list3 = []
for name in list2:
  for person in list1:
    if name ==  person[0]:
      list3.append(person)
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight solution:

```
list3 = [x for x in list1 if x[0] in list2]
```

Answer (score 0):

So essentially what you want to do is you **iterate** over the names in list2 and then check if the name in list2 is **present** in the sub-list of list1.

```
list1 = [("Joe Black", "married", "happy"),("Mili Cis", "unmarried" , "happy"),("Gary Oldman", "married", "unhappy")]
list2 = ["Joe Black","Gary Oldman"]
list3= []
for name in list2:
    for item in list1:
        for sub_item in item:
            if name == sub_item:
                list3.append(item)

print(list3)
```